# Inconsistencies on the required rep to create tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, tag-creation, meta-faq

According to [a recent blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/), the rep required to create a new tag has been raised to 1500.  Most of the documentation explaining rep has not yet been updated.  I just updated the [FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow) which explains rep; however, the FAQs are still out of date.  SO and MSO both show 500 as the required rep; SU and SF both still show 100.  Can we get an update to the FAQs please?

Answer (score 1):

The FAQs are already correct, as the change to 1500 reputation required applies to only Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow FAQ:

> 1500   Create new tags